# How to configure template for Azure Notification Hubs to use buttons in notification

Tags: push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am sending notifications to my app users (IOS and Android) via Azure Notifications Hub. To do this, i am using templates for both opering systems in my .NET backend. These templates look like this:

Android:
 `"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(message)\", \"title\": \"$(title)\"}}"`

IOS:
`"{\"aps\":{\"alert\": {\"title\":\"$(title)\",\"body\":\"$(message)\"}}}";`

This works fine, but now I would like to add buttons to my notifications for 2FA on login for my website. The user then can 'accept' or 'deny' the login via this notification.

My question is; How can i accomplish these buttons via my templates?